# Change input colour while typing password

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, onkeyup

I am working on a signup form and I am having trouble with this last section. I need the input border to turn from red to green once all the correct keys have been put in. I mean it to happen at the time of typing and not after submitting.
So it is red to begin but it turns green once you have pressed all the keys needed.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("signup-form");
const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
const passwordField = document.getElementById('password');
const confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
const confirmPasswordField = document.getElementById('confirm_password');

function formValidation(){
  // Password Field
  passwordField.style.borderColor = "red";
  passwordField.classList.add("invalid");

  if(password === ""){
    passwordField.style.borderColor = "red";
    passwordField.classList.add("invalid");
    return false;
  }else{
    passwordField.style.borderColor = "green";
    passwordField.classList.remove("invalid");
    passwordField.classList.add("valid");
  }
}    

function passwordFieldValidations() {
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
  var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");

  // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
  passwordField.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
  passwordField.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
  }

  passwordField.onkeyup = function() {

    // Validate lowercase letters
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if(passwordField.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
      letter.classList.remove("invalid");
      letter.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      letter.classList.remove("valid");
      letter.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate capital letters
    var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
    if(passwordField.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
     capital.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
     capital.classList.remove("valid");
     capital.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(passwordField.value.match(numbers)) {  
      number.classList.remove("invalid");
      number.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      number.classList.remove("valid");
      number.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate length
    if(passwordField.value.length >= 8) {
      length.classList.remove("invalid");
      length.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      length.classList.remove("valid");
      length.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    if (letter.classList.contains(valid) && capital.classList.contains(valid) 
        && number.classList.contains(valid) && length.classList.contains(valid)) {
      passwordField.style.borderColor = "green";
      passwordField.classList.remove("invalid");
      passwordField.classList.add("valid");
    }
  }
}

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    var password1 = passwordField.value;
    var password2 = confirmPasswordField.value;
    if(password1 !== password2) {
        e.preventDefault()
        confirmPasswordField.style.borderColor = "red";
        confirmPasswordField.classList.add("invalid");
    } else { 
        confirmPasswordField.style.borderColor = "green";
        confirmPasswordField.classList.remove("invalid");
        confirmPasswordField.classList.add("valid");
    }
});

document.getElementById("submit-form").addEventListener("click", formValidation);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

h1, h2 { font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; color: #fff; }

p, label, button { font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; }

#wrapper { width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; }

#content { background-color: #272224; height: 600px; padding: 20px 0 0; }

#signup-info { margin: 0 auto; }

#signup-form { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }

#signup-info h2 img { width: 40px; vertical-align: middle; }

#signup-info h1 { margin-bottom: 0; }

.no-top-margin { margin-top: 0; }

#signup-info p { color: #FFE4CF; }

label { display: block; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; }

input { margin-bottom: 15px; border: none; border-bottom: 1px #555 solid; 
        background-color: transparent; padding: 10px 0; width: 100%;
        color: #FFE4CF; font-weight: bold;
}

::placeholder { font-weight: normal; }

button { border: none; background-color: #FFE4CF; width: 100%; padding: 15px; font-weight: bold; }

#signup-info a { color: #fff; }

input.valid { background-image: url(images/check.png); background-position: right; 
              background-size: 10%; background-repeat: no-repeat; }

input.invalid { background-image: url(images/cross.png); background-position: right;
                background-size: 10%; background-repeat: no-repeat; }

#message p { margin: 5px 0 5px 40px; }

#message h3 { margin: 0 0 5px 0; }

#message .valid { color: green; }

#message .valid:before { position: relative; left: -35px; content: "✔"; }
  
/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
#message .invalid { color: red; }
  
#message .invalid:before { position: relative; left: -35px; content: "✖"; }

#message { display: none; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; }

input.valid:focus { outline: none !important; border:1px solid green; }

::-ms-reveal { filter: invert(100%); }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="signup-info">
      <form name="signup-form" id="signup-form" action="#" method="post">
        <div>
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter a password" 
                 pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" 
                 title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required onfocus="passwordFieldValidations()">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Retype password" 
                 title="Password must match" required onkeyup="matchPasswords()">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-form">Create account</button>
        <div id="message">
          <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
          <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
          <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
          <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
          <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than us having to sift through your code, can you tell us what aspect of your use case isn't working and what (if any) errors you are recieving?

Comment: Use the `input` event rather than `keyup` to get real time event processing as keystrokes are entered into your text fields.

Comment: Don't use event properties (i.e., onXyz) to set up events. Use the modern API of `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: Why are you using an `h3`? Is is nested within an `h2` that you aren't showing us?

Comment: You are using the `classList` API (good), but why are you also setting inline styles (bad)?

Comment: If you open the browser console, you will see the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: valid is not defined". First, fix this error by changing the undefined valid to a string "valid". letter.classList.contains(valid) -> letter.classList.contains("valid")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually pretty close. :)

You accidentally used `valid` as an identifier instead of a string in the `classList.contains(valid)` expression near the end of the password verification section:

```js
// contains(valid) should be contains("valid") in all this calls:
if (letter.classList.contains(valid) && capital.classList.contains(valid) 
        && number.classList.contains(valid) && length.classList.contains(valid)) {
      passwordField.style.borderColor = "green";
      passwordField.classList.remove("invalid");
      passwordField.classList.add("valid");
} else {
  // You also need to add an else here, change the borderColor to "red", add "invalid", remove "valid", and you're done!
}
```

**Tip:** Always have the browser console open when working with JavaScript in order to detect any errors and warnings early on an fix them.

Another trick that you can use (which leads to cleaner and more maintainable code) is to define a variable `hasErrors` at the beginning of the onkeyup event handler, assign the value false, and then set the value to true once `any` of the following checks fails.

Here's the basic logic behind this:

```js
    var hasErrors = false;

    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(passwordField.value.match(numbers)) {  
      ...
    } else {
      hasErrors = true;
      ...
    }

    // Validate length
    if(passwordField.value.length >= 8) {
      ...
    } else {
      hasErrors = true;
      ...
    }

    if ( hasErrors ) {
      // Handle error case (e.g. red border)
    } else {
      // Handle success (e.g. green border) 
    }
```

Also, as `Scott Marcus` mentioned, it's better to use the `addEventListener("keyup")` form instead of the `onkeyup`. Here's a [nice extensive SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/4861760) that explains the benefits of using the former.

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't believe I didn't notice that. I'm still learning and trip up on these things a lot. I actually did have the console open but I'm not good at reading the errors so I didn't get why it was telling me that as I didn't recognise the error I'd made.
I appreciate the help. I'll look into changing it to addEventListener also.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with transform variable password to let and then in the function formValidation() set variable password with document.getElementById('password').value;

```js
const form = document.getElementById("signup-form");
let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
const passwordField = document.getElementById('password');
const confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
const confirmPasswordField = document.getElementById('confirm_password');

function formValidation(){

    // Password Field
//set password value again

  password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  passwordField.style.borderColor = "red";
        passwordField.classList.add("invalid");

    if(password === ""){
        passwordField.style.borderColor = "red";
        passwordField.classList.add("invalid");
        return false;
    }else{
        passwordField.style.borderColor = "green";
        passwordField.classList.remove("invalid");
        passwordField.classList.add("valid");
    }
}    

function passwordFieldValidations() {
    var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
    var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var length = document.getElementById("length");

    // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
        passwordField.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
    passwordField.onblur = function() {
        document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
    }

    passwordField.onkeyup = function() {

    // Validate lowercase letters
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if(passwordField.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
        letter.classList.remove("invalid");
        letter.classList.add("valid");
        } else {
        letter.classList.remove("valid");
        letter.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate capital letters
    var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
    if(passwordField.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
        capital.classList.remove("invalid");
        capital.classList.add("valid");
        } else {
        capital.classList.remove("valid");
        capital.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(passwordField.value.match(numbers)) {  
        number.classList.remove("invalid");
        number.classList.add("valid");
        } else {
        number.classList.remove("valid");
        number.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate length
    if(passwordField.value.length >= 8) {
        length.classList.remove("invalid");
        length.classList.add("valid");
        } else {
        length.classList.remove("valid");
        length.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    if  (letter.classList.contains(valid) && capital.classList.contains(valid) 
        && number.classList.contains(valid) && length.classList.contains(valid)) {
        passwordField.style.borderColor = "green";
        passwordField.classList.remove("invalid");
        passwordField.classList.add("valid");
        }

    }
    
}


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    var password1 = passwordField.value;
    var password2 = confirmPasswordField.value;
    if(password1 !== password2) {
        e.preventDefault()
        confirmPasswordField.style.borderColor = "red";
        confirmPasswordField.classList.add("invalid");
    } else { 
        confirmPasswordField.style.borderColor = "green";
        confirmPasswordField.classList.remove("invalid");
        confirmPasswordField.classList.add("valid");
    }
});

document.getElementById("submit-form").addEventListener("click", formValidation);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

h1,
h2 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

p,
label,
button {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    background-color: #272224;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
}

#signup-info {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#signup-form {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#signup-info h2 img {
    width: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#signup-info h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.no-top-margin {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#signup-info p {
    color: #FFE4CF;
}

label {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px #555 solid;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFE4CF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

::placeholder {
    font-weight: normal;
}

button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #FFE4CF;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#signup-info a {
    color: #fff;
}

input.valid {
    background-image: url(images/check.png);
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input.invalid {
    background-image: url(images/cross.png);
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#message p {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 40px;
}

#message h3 {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#message .valid {
    color: green;
  }

#message .valid:before {
    position: relative;
    left: -35px;
    content: "✔";
  }
  
  /* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
#message .invalid {
    color: red;
  }
  
#message .invalid:before {
    position: relative;
    left: -35px;
    content: "✖";
  }

#message {
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

input.valid:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid green;
  }

::-ms-reveal {
filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="content">

                <div id="signup-info">
                    

                    <form name="signup-form" id="signup-form" action="#" method="post">
                       
                        <div>
                            <label for="password">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter a password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" 
                            title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required onfocus="passwordFieldValidations()">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Retype password" 
                            title="Password must match" required onkeyup="matchPasswords()">
                        </div>
                        
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-form">Create account</button>

                        <div id="message">
                            <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
                            <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
                            <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
                            <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
                            <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
                        </div>
                    
                    </form>

                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```